# Mindstorms: EV3 Brick files vanished

Tags: mindstorms

The EV3 brick turned off by itself (the battery is not low), we restarted it and the file finder was empty, all our files are not there right now. Have they disappeared from the brick forever or is there a way to restore them(without re-downloading)?

This has never happened before, what are some of the reasons this might happen?

We tried a reset with the very top, and center buttons, it did not return our files.

Comment: what is the problem with uploading the code into the brick again?

Comment: That works, however, it's the first time files just randomly disappeared. I wondered if they were playing peekaboo and going to resurface some time later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The files are no longer accessible from the brick.  You will have to re-download them.  The EV3 operating system (LMS2012) is sensitive to unexpected shutdowns.  When an unexpected shutdown occurs, information is lost in the internal memory of the device.  There is no hard-drive inside the EV3.  So, programs are stored in a Flash Memory chip.  I have found from personal experience that all of the file in the user programs folder are wiped out and disappear completely as if they never existed on the brick.  Sorry.  That has been my experience.